# SSRS Report with Tree like structure

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2

I want to create Tree like structure as SSRS report output.

Currently my stored procedure giving following patterns as output. Now i want to 
show this output in a tree manner.

```
Menu Name    Navigation Key   Parent Key
Home          1               0
Setting 1     2               1
Setting 2     3               1
Setting 3     4               1
Registration  5               0
Login 1       6               5
Login 2       7               5
```

Now i want to display tree structure in SSRS report.

Exm :

```
Home
     Setting 1
     Setting 2
     Setting 3
Registration
    Login 1
    Login 2
```

Any idea/help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks
Dilip

Comment: What does your query look like for this data?

Comment: If you only have two levels, just set an expression on the cell's left padding or left margin property something like `=IIF(Fields!ParentKey.Value=0, "2px", "10px")`